# How do I update a table in the database securely using an input from a html form?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I have a html table where I need to take the users input safely and securely to update a table item. Any guidance? (I know what I've wrote below is incorrect)

For example if they wanted to update their own details for example surname:

```
<div class="grid-2"> 
    <p><b>UPDATE MY DETAILS</b></p>
    <form action ="includes/update.inc.php" method ="post">
        <label>S.Name</label>
        <input name="update-surname" type="text" placeholder="Enter new surname...">
        <label>Address</label>
        <input name="update-houseno" type="text" placeholder="Enter house no' or name...">
        <input name="update-ln1" type="text" placeholder="1st Line of Address...">
        <input name="update-town" type="text" placeholder="Town...">
        <input name="update-county" type="text" placeholder="County...">
        <input name="update-postcode" type="text" placeholder="Postcode...">
        <label>Contact Number</label>
        <input name="update-number" type="text" placeholder="Contact Number...">
        <label>Email</label>
        <input name="update-email" type="text" placeholder="Email...">
        <input type="submit" name="update-details" value="Update">
    </form>
</div>
```

Update name snapshot.....
[image: Update the name]

UPDATE I have added code to the above page and an action on the form as requested. The code below is the start of what I've made to the page the action leads to:

```
    <?php
    // Here we check whether the user got to this page by clicking the proper button.
    if (isset($_POST['update-details'])) {

          require 'dbh.inc.php';

    // We grab all the data which we passed from the update form so we can use it later.
        $surname = $_POST['update-surname'];
        $houseno = $_POST['update-houseno'];
        $ln1 = $_POST['update-ln1'];
        $town = $_POST['update-town'];
        $county = $_POST['update-county'];
        $postcode = $_POST['update-postcode'];
        $number = $_POST['update-number'];
        $email = $_POST['update-email'];

          // We validate email is correct if email has been updated. 
      if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        header("Location: ../after-login.php?error=invalidmail&uid=");
        exit();
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: did u tried anything? please share

Comment: phpmyadmin is not a database, it is a database client.  I assume you have a mysql database with a `tblMember` table?

Comment: Hi, yes mysql running in phpmyadmin I meant to say. I have a `tblMember` where I just want to take the input of what the user types (so say if they wanted to update their last name on a dashboard), it would then update that in `tblMember`.

Comment: when are you expecting the update to happen, on user input, on form submit, etc?

Comment: Hi @jameson2012 so just when the user hits the submit button, so onClick

Comment: Are you using mysql_* or mysqli_*?

Comment: mysqli @KebabProgrammer

Comment: It seems you have everything already, just add your SQL statement in the `isset($_POST['update-details'])` for updating your record, as well as having a field for storing the username of the user

Comment: Did you get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need an action on your form - i.e a script to point it to to process the form (can be the same script).  You also ideally want to set the method to post so that data isn't visible in the url then you need to clean your data, connect to the db and do your query.

This should help you get the right idea

[Form in PDO to update data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29586585/form-in-pdo-to-update-data)

Comment: Thank you so much, I'll take a look at that right away!! :)